# CertUtil Windows Update gives me 430+ certificates?

Tags: certificate, windows-update

There are several well known methods of downloading certificate lists from Microsoft, including
certutil -generateSSTfromWU c:\my_cert\

Doing that (or just downloading authrootstl.cab) gives me a collection of more than 400 root certificates.

Now, I know that none of my connected servers have that many certificates loaded: and I just looked at a Win10 workstation and it has ~90 trusted root certificates and around 70 third-party root certificates.

Why is it so?  How many trusted root certificates does Windows start with, and why is there this much larger list?

Comment: Windows includes the most common root CA's. There's no linkage with what ships with Windows, and the authorities that have qualified and are registered with the Trusted Root CA program.

Comment: in total, there is around 400 trusted roots in Windows Root Program. Someone just unloaded the full CTL into certificate store.